# Extending/overriding jQuery object literal methods - Out of scope issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-plugins

I have very little experience writing jQuery plugins and even less experience using JavaScript design patterns, so please bear with me.

I am using the singleton pattern in a jQuery extension I'm writing. That works fine, however I want to be able to extend/override methods and properties of my singleton object.

To accomplish this, I have a master `var self = {}` object that, at runtime, will contain a properties object literal and a methods object literal. The individual properties and methods of their respective object literals will be set to defaults or an options parameter if one was passed in.

This also works, until you pass in a method that tries to access `self.properties` or `self.methods`. Because `self` is only defined in the singleton object and not the object literal I want to pass in, a JavaScript error is thrown before anything is even passed.

To better understand this, below I have created a full example that very closely resembles what I am trying to do.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    $.extend({
        MyObject : function(options) {

            // enfore singleton pattern
            $.MyObject = function() {
                if(typeof $.MyObject != 'undefined') { // if an instance exists
                    console.log('$.MyObject is a singleton - original instance returned');
                    return $.MyObject; // return original instance
                }
                else return this; // else, return this instance
            };

            var self = {},
            defaults = {
                properties : {
                    prop : true,
                    foo : "bar"
                },
                methods : {
                    main : function() {
                        console.log(self.properties.foo); // console logs "bar"
                    }
                }
            };

            this.init = function(options) {
                self = $.extend({}, defaults, options); // set properties to defaults unless options were provided
                self.methods.main();
            };

            this.init(options);

            return this;
        }

    });

})( jQuery, window, document );

$(window).load(function() {
    $.MyObject({
        properties : {
            foo : "baz"
        },
        methods : {
            main : function() {
                if(self.properties.prop) { // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined
                    console.log(self.properties.foo); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have probably drastically over-complicated what I am trying to do. At this point, I am thinking there is probably a better way to do this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a deep extend in init().  You might also pass in the current options as "this" via call() on main().

```js
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
  $.extend({
    MyObject : function(options) {

      // ---------------
      // enforce singleton pattern
      // ---------------
      $.MyObject = function() {
        if (typeof $.MyObject === 'undefined') { return this; }
        console.log('$.MyObject is a singleton...');
        return $.MyObject;
      };
      // ---------------

      // ---------------
      // establish default options
      // ---------------
      var self = {};
      var defaults = {
        properties : {
          prop : true,
          foo : "bar"
        },
        methods : {
          main : function() { console.log( this.properties.foo ); }
        }
      };
      // ---------------

      // ---------------
      // Override default options and execute main() in the context
      // of our current options
      // ---------------
      this.init = function(options) {
        self = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
        self.methods.main.call(self);
      };
      this.init(options);
      // ---------------

      return this;
    }
  });
})( jQuery, window, document );

$(window).load(function() {
  var options = {
    properties : {
      bar : "foo"
    },
    methods : {
      main : function() {
        if(this.properties.prop) { console.log(this.properties.bar); }
      }
    }
  };

  $.MyObject(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aw man, I was close. I'm not familiar with the deep extend or the call() function but I'll get to studying those. Thank you for your help!